# C++ container and openCL

Tags: c++, arrays, containers, opencl

I am looking into some C++ code which extensively uses `boost::multi_array<double>`.

The next step is to port the code to use openCL. As I'm quite new to openCL I don't know what I should do with the `multi_array`. Should I rewrite it into a `nested-openCL-vector` or `nested-c-array`.

What would you do?

Comment: Probably depends on what you're going to do with it

Comment: I'll wanna some fixed sized array to put into gpu's memory and let some calculations do by the card.

Comment: What kind of data does your boost::mult_array contain? What are the dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

There are boost like libraries already exist for OpenCL, you may want to look at the  following libraries from GPU Vendors

Thurst from NVIDIA: Thrust is a powerful library of parallel algorithms and data structures.  Thrust provides a flexible, high-level interface for GPU programming that greatly enhances developer productivity. Using Thrust, C++ developers can write just a few lines of code to perform GPU-accelerated sort, scan, transform, and reduction operations orders of magnitude faster than the latest multi-core CPUs.  For example, the thrust::sort algorithm delivers 5x to 100x faster sorting performance than STL and TBB.

AMD offers Math Libraries are software libraries containing FFT and BLAS functions written in OpenCL and designed to run on AMD GPUs for more info look here:
http://developer.amd.com/libraries/appmathlibs/Pages/default.aspx